# SocketIO when server is down the clientside gives a window alert of undefined?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When i execute and start my server file e.g.

```
 node app.js
```

and then i force stop the server by exiting the node console or CTRL-C how come i get a window alert of **UNDEFINED**

e.g.

```
window.alert(undefined);
```

i know for a fact its not coming from my code so it must be coming from the socketio package but if so can i errorHandle this? and instead of alert undefined it could alert the user that the server is down or cannot be reached?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: just to add as a note, i know about the sockets.on('connection') to listen for socket connection and socket.on("disconnect") which just states when the server cannot reach the client, not when the client cant reach the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Client events (not all)

- `socket.on('disconnect', function () {})` - "disconnect" is emitted when the socket disconnected
- `socket.on('connect_failed', function () {})` - "connect_failed" is emitted when socket.io fails to establish a connection to the server and has no more transports to fallback to.
- `socket.on('error', function () {})` - "error" is emitted when an error occurs and it cannot be handled by the other event types.

Looks like in some place of your code (client) you have a `alert(socket);` or something like this.

check the client socketio file too.